# My app project doesn't get pushed in GitHub

Tags: android, github

" Cannot run program "git.exe":
 CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

This is the message I get everytime I try to get into Version Control System  > import into version control > share project on github 
Why is it??
I have gitbash in my system already.

Answer (score 0):

Check you Android Studio settings:

```
File->Settings->Version Control->git "Path to Git executable"
```

Put the path you have for your git.exe: you can download and uncompress [the latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) anywhere you want (like the [`PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.19.0-64-bit.7z.exe) self-extracting archive one).